# Forms - Managing OneToMany collection elements

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

Let's imagine these 2 entities:

```
ShoppingCart
    creationDate

Item
    name
    shoppingCart  # ManyToOne
```

I'm managing a `ShoppingCart` in a form with a `CollectionType` of `Items`

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...
    $builder
    // ...
        ->add('items', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ItemFormType::class,
    // ...
}
```

I'd like my users to be able to **add/remove** items, which seems to me like a quite common need.

If I understand well, here is what I have to do:

- Define the reverse `OneToMany` side of the `ShoppingCart` relation to `Item`
- Make sure this relation have the `cascade={"persist"}` and `orphanRemoval=true` options
- Initialize this items `Collection` into the constructor
- Set the `allow_add` and `allow_delete` form option to **true**
- Set the `by_reference` form option to **false**
- Make sure `andItem()` & `removeItem()` functions are implemented into `ShoppingCart`
- Set/unset the owning side relation to the `ShoppingCart` in addition to add/remove the `Item` from the `ShoppingCart` items collection
- Keep the collection indexes within javascript so Doctrine can keep track of references

Am I forgetting something ?

I find it a big pain in the arse for me compared to the need and to other frameworks/ORMs

**Is there a way to do it simpler ?**

Comment: You didn't mention what is the problem. Is there something not working?

Comment: Doc will confirm all your items (or not) : http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: @dragoste the question is *isn't it simpler ?* but I'm going to change so it is more explicit. @DOZ I know this doc by heart (There is only the `orphanRemoval` mention missing)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your question is "why is it so complicated", isn't it?

Well, it's not. You've listed things multiple layers in your project. To exaggerate the point a little bit - why didn't you wrote that in order to create this form you need to install Symfony or even turn on your computer. ;-)

Anyway, most of these things are not required, others should be done before anyway.

Let's start with your OneToMany relation (Doctrine level).

`ShoppingCart` is your aggregate root (DDD term, but it doesn't matter if you follow DDD idea), which means you probably will do most of work on this object which will handle `Item`s inside. If so, then you should have done inversed side of the relation, which covers these points (I think you went into details so much to make your list longer ;-), they all should be in one list item), but it takes a minute to do this stuff:

> - Define the reverse OneToMany side of the ShoppingCart relation to Item
> - Make sure this relation have the cascade={"persist"} and orphanRemoval=true options
> - Initialize this items Collection into the constructor
> - Make sure andItem() & removeItem() functions are implemented into ShoppingCart
> - Set/unset the owning side relation to the ShoppingCart in addition to add/remove the Item from the ShoppingCart items collection

This has nothing to do with forms. It's about how you want your entities to work with Doctrine.

Following two are not required:

> - Set the allow_add and allow_delete form option to true
> - Set the by_reference form option to false

They are about enabling/disabling features. You want them, so you need to use them. That's obvious and still not so much to do.

Last one:

> - Keep the collection indexes within javascript so Doctrine can keep track of references

This is the one that I actually don't understand. But what you need (in your case, because you're using allow_add/delete feature), is to provide JavaScript code that will create HTML for new row or delete existing one. But that's also just about copying prototype code. Also there are ready examples in Symfony's doc.

Comment: 1 - I know what aggregate root is, I'm talking from an objective point of view (and in comparison with other frameworks/ORMs)

Comment: 2 - Objectively, since I can already link an `Item` to a `ShoppingCart`, those first points are talking about that should already be there, are not

Comment: 3 - Do you actually find easy to setup an aggregate root with Doctrine ?

Comment: 4 - The 3 form options are indeed required to allow add/delete

Comment: 5 - In the last point, I was thinking of a more efficient way to synchronize the objects but this will eventually by a github issue

Comment: @2 You actually can already link `ShoppingCart` to `Item`, not vice versa. That's the point. There are uni~  and bidirectional associations in Doctrine. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: @3 I'm usually implementing domain layer almost completely separate from any framework/ORM, therefore I'm not following Symfony's standard coding way.

Comment: @4 Yes they are required for you **right now in this case**. But if there were by default set to the values that you **currently** want, you could complain in other cases that you would need to disable everything when you would like just a simple collection. Disabling features by default is a good convention in my opinion.

Comment: I get you. I understand the Symfony/Doctrine logics (Java copy/pasted) and I was hoping to get some more "modern" techniques to deal it with SF3. So I seem to have my answer: no :)

Comment: I think that in general it's rapid development vs flexibility of framework. Other frameworks let you do some things quicker, but it's hard to do something custom with them.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer myself in a simpler manner:

- No I am not forgetting anything
- No we can't do simpler

Some reasons are explained in @dragoste [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39099052/305189)